matplotlibで凡例をtwinyより、前面に表示する方法
matplotlibで、以下のコードを実行したところ、
凡例が横棒グラフ(緑のエリア)の後ろに表示されてしまいました。
凡例を、最前面に表示する方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。
（できれば、凡例の塗りつぶし色は、半透明にしたいです。）
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# 折れ線グラフ
ax.plot([0, 1, 2], [300, 305, 310], marker='o', label='data1')
ax.plot([0, 1, 2], [300, 310, 320], marker='o', label='data2')

# 横棒グラフ
twin_ax = ax.twiny()
twin_ax.barh(300, 500, color='#00ff0080', height=5)  # 半透明で描画
# twin_ax.set_zorder(1)

# 凡例
legend = ax.legend(loc='lower left')
legend.set_zorder(1000)
# legend.get_frame().set_alpha(1.0)

plt.show()



zorder の設定が効かないので、ax から凡例の属性値を取り出して twin_ax 側に貼り付けます。
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# 折れ線グラフ
ax.plot([0, 1, 2], [300, 305, 310], marker='o', label='data1')
ax.plot([0, 1, 2], [300, 310, 320], marker='o', label='data2')

# 横棒グラフ
twin_ax = ax.twiny()
twin_ax.barh(300, 500, color='#00ff0080', height=5)  # 半透明で描画

# 凡例
legend = twin_ax.legend(*ax.get_legend_handles_labels(), loc='lower left')
legend.get_frame().set_alpha(0.3)

plt.show()



できました。ありがとうございます。

fig.get_axes()より取得したaxesのリストから、zorderが最大かつ最後に設定されたaxeに、legendを設定すればよいということですよね。動的にaxesがかわるグラフでも、汎用化できそうです、やってみます。

"Artist" の構成要素の関係上
Axes 内に legendsがあり, その中での順序になります
なので, Axes順序変更すると良いでしょう
参考: (matplotlib.org) "Artist" チュートリアル
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# 折れ線グラフ
ax.plot([0, 1, 2], [300, 305, 310], marker='o', label='data1')
ax.plot([0, 1, 2], [300, 310, 320], marker='o', label='data2')
ax.set_zorder(2)   #  (legendが含まれるので) 高めに

# 横棒グラフ
twin_ax = ax.twiny()
twin_ax.barh(300, 500, color='#00ff0080', height=5)  # 半透明で描画
twin_ax.set_zorder(1)   #  有効化

# 凡例
legend = ax.legend(loc='lower left')
legend.set_zorder(1000)
# legend.get_frame().set_alpha(1.0)

ax.patch.set_alpha(0)   #  棒グラフも見えるように
plt.show()


ありがとうございます。twin_ax.set_zorder(1)も実行することで、うまくいきました。

ax.set_axisbelow(True)およびax.grid(True)を付けた場合は、グリッド線が手前にくることも理解できました。


twin_ax.set_zorder(1)も実行することで
... たぶんバージョンによって異なるのでしょう。 colabでは指定なしでも動作。でも やはりどちらかと言えば両方指定したほうがよいかも

